# JavaFX Pagination, leaking on setPageFactory?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

In the example below if one continues to press the "Next group" button, eventually the application heap will be exhausted.  Set the heap to a low number such as -mx50m -ms50m and it will quickly hit the ceiling.  You can see the classic staircase memory consumption occurring with something like JVisualVM.  In profiling with YourKit it was found there were many object instances from the javafx.* and java.* class packages that are not being CG'ed.  setPageFactory seems to be the culprit.  Perhaps this bit of code is doing something is should not, but so far I'm suspecting the JavaFX 2.2 Pagination control on Windows 8, JDK 1.7_60.  The same problem is seen with Window 8, Java FX 8, JDK 1.8_05.

Is this a problem with the example or JavaFX Pagination.setPageFactory?

```
public class PaginationSample extends Application {
    private static final String[] PAGE_TEXTS_0 = {"Time wounds all heals.", "The more I see, the less I know for sure.", 
    "Reality leaves a lot to the imagination.", "It's weird not to be weird."};
    private static final String[] PAGE_TEXTS_1 = {"Fermions", "Quarks", "Leptons", "Bosons", "Gluon", "Graviton"};
    private static final String[] PAGE_TEXTS_2 = {"AAAAAAA", "BBBBB", "CCCCCCCC"};
    private static final String[][] ALL_GROUPS = {PAGE_TEXTS_0, PAGE_TEXTS_1, PAGE_TEXTS_2};

    private int groupIndex;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        final Pagination pagination = new Pagination();
        setPagesGroup(pagination);

        Button button = new Button("Next group");
        button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                nextGroup();
                setPagesGroup(pagination);
            }
        });

        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
        pane.setCenter(pagination);
        pane.setBottom(button);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(pane, 400, 250));
        stage.setTitle("What's leaking?");

        stage.show();
    }

    private void setPagesGroup(Pagination pagination) {
        pagination.setPageFactory(createPageFactory());
        pagination.setPageCount(ALL_GROUPS[groupIndex].length);
    }

    private Callback<Integer, Node> createPageFactory() {
        return new Callback<Integer, Node>() {
            @Override
            public Node call(Integer pageIndex) {
                return createPage(ALL_GROUPS[groupIndex][pageIndex]);
            }

            private Node createPage(String text) {
                return new Label(text);
            }
        };
    }

    private void nextGroup() {
        if (++groupIndex == ALL_GROUPS.length) {
            groupIndex = 0;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Evidence in profiler during test below.  Before and at end of test the garbage collection was forced.

[image: YourKit showing heap being consumption while clicking the button]

Additional investigation:

If the line

```
//  pagination.setPageFactory(createPageFactory());
```

is commented out the example still works since the factory is still delivering the pages and the setPageCount method forces the PaginationSkin class to call its resetIndexes method.  Both setPageFactory and setPageCount invoke PaginationSkin.resetIndexes and the memory consumption occurs.  Perhaps there is something wrong with [PaginationSkin.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.java.openjfx.backport/openjfx-78-backport/1.8.0-ea-b96.1/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/PaginationSkin.java)?

Answer (score 5):

Please vote for the issue to be resolved, you will have to login.

https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-38058

Java 7 and 8 code calling

```
    pagination.setPageFactory(...);
    pagination.setPageCount(...);
```

will incur this leak.

---

There appears to be a leak in the PaginationSkin class. To verify copy the source from

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/2.2.2/master/rt/file/98d1e63be240/javafx-ui-controls/src/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/PaginationSkin.java

then through the process of elimination and profiling the memory you will find these two add listeners in the inner class IndicatorButton are causing the leak:

```
@ line 1179

            getSkinnable().getStyleClass().addListener(new ListChangeListener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onChanged(Change<? extends String> change) {
                    setIndicatorType();
                }
            });


@ line 1197

            tooltipVisibleProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> ov, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
                    setTooltipVisible(newValue);
                }
            });
```

Because of inner class back references the garbage collector cannot remove these objects event after the IndicatorButton objects are removed from the node tree (getChildren.clear()). In an IDE, if you temporarily make IndicatorButton static you can break the compilation and see the highlighted references to the outer class. When these two listeners are commented out, the leak goes away. If you leave these two listeners in, and comment out the lines of working code inside the listener the leak still occurs.

Solution:

1. Create your own version of PaginationSkin (source link above) and apply it to your Pagination control object (via pagination.setSkin or CSS)
2. In your class modify IndicatorButton class to have a release() method that will release the added listeners
3. Before getChildren.clear() is called to release the indicatorButtons, call release on each IndicatorButton object.

Comment: Yes fixed, details [here: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8096540](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8096540)

Comment: Thanks a lot @javajon